# Error when using java packages

Tags: java, import, package

I am writing a game. Its directory tree is basically like this:

```
ShootGame------>game----------------------->input--------------------------------->InputHandler.class
            |-->ShooterGame.class     |                                        |-->InputHandler.java
            |-->ShooterGame.java      |---->player-------------->Player.class                        
                                      |                      |-->Player.java
                                      |---->scenario---
                                                      |-->Block.class
                                                      |-->Block.java
```

I hope you understand my diagram, but the point is: the "game" folder has 3 folders inside it, "input","player","scenario".

Inside "InputHandler.java", I have declared `package game.input`.

Inside "Player.java", I have declared `package game.player`.

And inside "Block.java", I have declared `package game.scenario`.

So far, so good.

But when, in the Player.java, i do `import game.input.InputHandler`, it says "package game.input does not exist", even though I have already declared "game.input".

What have I done wrong here? If you need the codes inside the files, please leave a comment. I am not posting them here because I think the main problem I have is the `package` and `import` logic.

Thanks.

Edit:

***Code***

InputHandler.java

```
package game.input;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class InputHandler implements KeyListener{

    static boolean[] keys = new boolean[256];

    public InputHandler(Component c){
        c.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public boolean isKeyDown(int keyCode){
        if (keyCode > 0 && keyCode < 256){
            return keys[keyCode];
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() > 0 && e.getKeyCode() < 256){
            keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() > 0 && e.getKeyCode() < 256){
            keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
}
```

Player.java

```
package game.player;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import game.input.InputHandler;

public class Player{

    private BufferedImage sprite;
    public int x, y, width, height;
    private final double speed = 5.0d;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        try{
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("ship.png");
            sprite = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch(IOException e){}
    }

    public void keyPlayer(double delta, InputHandler i){
        if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_D)){
            if(this.x>=1240) return;
            else this.x+=speed*delta;
        }

        if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_A)){
            if(this.x<=0) return;
            else this.x-=speed*delta;
        }

    }

    public void update(InputHandler inputP){
        keyPlayer(1.7, inputP);
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics a){
        a.drawImage(sprite,x,y,width,height,null);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
    }
}
```

Block.java

```
package game.scenario;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Block{

    private Timer timer;
    private BufferedImage sprite;
    private final int t = 1;
    public int x, y, width, height;

    public Block(int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;

        try{
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("meteor.png");
            sprite = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch(IOException e){}
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(sprite,x,y,width,height,null);
    }

    public boolean destroy(Block b){
        if(b.y>=630){
            b = null;
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    public void update(int sec){
        //if(getBounds().intersects(ShooterGame.ShooterGameClass.player.getBounds())){ System.out.println("Collision detected!"); }
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Move(), sec*1000);
        destroy(this);
    }

    class Move extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            int keeper = 5;
            if(keeper>0){
                y+=5;
            }
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
    }

}
```

The main class(The game start)
ShooterGame.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import game.input.InputHandler;
import game.player.Player;
import game.scenario.Block;

public class ShooterGame extends JFrame{
    static int playerX=500;
    static int playerY=520;

    InputHandler input = new InputHandler(this);
    public static Player player = new Player(playerX,playerY,50,50);
    Block meteor = new Block(100,100,30,30);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ShooterGame game = new ShooterGame();
        game.run();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    static int windowWidth = 1300;
    static int windowHeight = 600;
    static int fps = 30;
    static BufferedImage backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    public void run(){
        boolean running = true;

        initialize();

        while(running){
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            update();
            draw();

            time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

            if (time > 0) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(time);
                }
                catch(Exception e){};
            };
        }
    }

    public void initialize(){
        setTitle("--- Shooter Game ---");
        setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update(){
        player.update(input);
        meteor.update(0);
    }

    public void draw(){

        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();

        bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bbg.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        player.Draw(bbg);
        meteor.Draw(bbg);

        g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Commands:

compiling Player, Block and InputHandler(javac *file*.java)
then run the game with **_java ShooterGame**

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Eclipse? What are you running and where are you seeing the error message? Where are you running a command from (if you are)?

Comment: I am running the file from the Command Prompt, and the message printed is exactly this one: "game\player\Player.java:10: error: package game.input does not exist", and I am not using any IDE

Comment: Edit your question and add what commands you run and from what directories. You are probably not compiling your project correctly or running it with the correct classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to compile from inside the directory that the file is in, which is incorrectly setting the classpath.

```
cd game/player
javac Player.java
```

Instead of going into the subpackages, set the classpath explicitly and compile from the top level. I'm assuming that `ShooterGame.java` is in your `game` folder:

```
cd path/to/project/ShootGame
javac -cp . game/player/Player.java
... compile other classes
java -cp . game.ShooterGame
```

Comment: I compiled my files(Thanks!) but when I do _java -cp . game.ShooterGame_, it says that it was unable to locate and load the main class game.ShooterGame. I think it may be something related to classpath(which I do not know much of). How can I fix it?

Comment: OP (sadly) didn't put `ShooterGame` in a package.